# how to set classpath for com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile() function?

Tags: java, jar, compiler-errors

I am using `com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile()` function to compile java file at run time from my struts projects. But for some files they need some specific jars like axis2. I have the jars but how can i set them to classpath to compile the java file at runtime? I have tried with `System.setProperty("java.class.path","jar dir");` but failed to compile.

Comment: using eclipse. those jars are in my lib.

Comment: okies, Have you added those jars in the run configuration CLASSPATH tab?

Comment: I would use the Compiler API rather attempting to call this function directly. It allows you set control the compilation. e.g. from memory, capture error messages.

Comment: look, when I put those java files in my project structure they are getting compiled fine. But in my application I will be getting some java files at runtime and I need to make class files from them at runtime. For compiling them they want some jar files. there is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following code which uses `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`  worked for me:

**Apple.java**

```
//This class is packaged in a jar named MyJavaCode.jar
import com.xyz.pqr.SomeJavaExamples;
public class Apple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello from Apple.main()");
    }
}
```

**AClass.java**

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class AClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Specify classpath using next to -cp
            //This looks just like how we specify parameters for javac
            String[] optionsAndSources = {
                "-g", "-source", "1.5",
                "-target", "1.5", 
                "-cp", ".:/home/JavaCode/MyJavaCode.jar",
                "Apple.java"
            };
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("./out.txt"));
            int status =  Main.compile(optionsAndSources, out);
            System.out.println("status: " + status);
            System.out.println("complete: ");
        }catch (Exception e) {}
    } 
}
```

Note: To compile this `AClass.java`, `tools.jar` needs to be in the `classpath`, which is not there by default, so you will have to specify it.

If you are using `Java 1.6` then you should consider using `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` instead, its [getTask(](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29)) methods takes an argument `options` which can have the `classpath`.

For example:

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;

public final class AClass {
    private static boolean compile(JavaFileObject... source ){
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        // set compiler's classpath to be same as the runtime's
        options.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
        //Add more options including classpath
        final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        final JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(/*default System.err*/ null,
            /*std file manager*/ null,
            /*std DiagnosticListener */  null,
            /*compiler options*/ options,
            /*no annotation*/  null,
            Arrays.asList(source));
       return task.call();
}
```

`com.sun.tools.javac.Main` is deprecated and undocumented too.

Comment: I was using java.class.path. Missing the '.' in question. But no joy