# Load process as a thread?

Tags: java

So I saw some code in passing that referenced `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`, and I got curious, can I run the java process AS A THREAD inside my process? Other executables? I've loaded other java programs from ClassLoaders and injected them with Java Agents, but now I'm curious, could one load an EXE inside java?

I assume it's possible with memory reading/writing, but there aught to be a safer way. (If not, where would one find some specification?)

Comment: Short answer no. Why would you want to do this? You can start a child `Process` (but this code won't execute "inside" the JVM) The only way to run native (machine code) inside a Java process that I know of would be to use JNI (but this will execute code in DLLs/Shared Objects and not an 'EXE' - so you can't run something like MS Word.exe "inside" the JVM)

Comment: @BretC Because Innovation is fun. I'm thinking of writing a JNA thread interface & performing some thread injection, however I don't know if that's possible in Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extendings the Answer by Banthar:
Every process on a system has his own adress space.:
Threads are so called light - weighted processes which are related to the parent - process they were started from.:
Within assembly code or C / C++ where you can directly access hardware adresses :
you could break into the adress space of another process perhaps, though :
usually the system which is responsible for creating them will try to avoid such things.:

AFAIK there is no direct access to a certain memory region not allocated by the :
process trying to access it. IPC (inter process communication) is a good starting point to find out more about how to connect processes

So no access to other processes not started by your process.:

Still you can start other java processes (threads are processes, too):
 or execute commandlines like 'java -jar xx.jar'.:
:

And of course nothing stops you from doing things such as calling a method on an object which is declared pulic such as static public void main within your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile classes in your code, if that is what your asking? See method getClass in https://github.com/tgkprog/jCompile/blob/master/JCompService/src/main/java/s2n/jComp/services/impl/DefaultClazzCompilerService.java

Can see other examples on the internet too. Javac compiler is just another written in Java tool since ages back. I'm guessing the next version of Java gets compiled by javac written in the previous version :) Sounds strange but fine if you think about what a java compiler does.

So you could call it as an API as above or make a process and call it (so its not part of your JVM just that your JVM invoked it). Not sure about calling the main method in a thread, i dont see why they would stop you. But it would not be heavy weight process, just an API call to the main mehtod if the class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(args);
}
```

Similar : [No com.sun.tools.javac in JDK7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314904/no-com-sun-tools-javac-in-jdk7) , [how to set classpath for com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246175/how-to-set-classpath-for-com-sun-tools-javac-main-compile-function)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in general. Executable files have to be loaded at specific address. This address is already occupied by java executable. In general one process can execute only one executable.

You can invoke other Java programs. Just add the jar to classpath and invoke `main()` method. That's probably how you saw `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` invoked.

If you have native shared library you can load it into java process with `System.loadLibrary`.

If you want to execute non-shared, native executable, the only way is to create new process.

Comment: Would it be possible to use some ASM modifications to the EXE to shift the entire thing to it's new location in memory? I've pulled off more retarded things.

Comment: You would have to correct all memory references and emulate per-process global state. I doubt that's possible for non-trivial executables. It would be simpler to write x86 emulator in Java and run that process in emulated environment. There must be an easier solution to your problem.